# Add dynamic images to an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, arraylist, jsx

In my global array of react project, where i add products, i have something like this:

```
   const ProductContext = createContext();

   export const ProductProvider = ({ children }) => {
   const [products, setProducts] = useState([
     {brand: 'The North Face', image: p1, price: '129,99', back_image: p1_back,},
   ]);
```

The array works but i was trying to add dynamically the images, without write manually into the array for each product the correspondent image (image: 'p1'. p1 is the name of the image imported for the first product). The goal so is to associate dynamically the image to id of products. I have set the id of each products in a dynamically way like this ;

```
    let idCounter = 1; 
    for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
      if (!products[i].id) {
        products[i].id = 'p' + idCounter;
        idCounter++;
      }
    }
```

As you can see, the first p1 product doesn't have the id, but in this way it will be dynamically assigned to it. I want exactly something like this, but for the image

So, I want something that allow me to with only importing the images, for example p1 and p1_back, and automatic assign them with the id to the corresponding product of the array, to the data image: ' ',and for the 2 image back_image ' '. I have tried to use the scheme of id, but that doesn't work. On my website the image doesn't appear. This is what i have tried (only for 'image', not for back_image).

```
  let imageCounter = 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    if (!products[i].image) {
      products[i].image = 'p' + imageCounter;
      imageCounter++;
    }
  }
```

The import are this;

```
       import p1 from './pagescomponents/images/productimages/p1.png';
       import p2_dietro from  './pagescomponents/images/productimages/p2_dietro.png';
```

The problem is not the array or something else, because the other data like id, brand works fine.

Please help me. Thanks for the time

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is to [dynamically import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import) the images rather than to dynamically assign the imports. Something along the lines of:

```js
const images = await Promise.all(products.map(async (product, i) => {
  return {
    ...product,
    image: await import(`./pagescomponents/images/productimages/p${i + 1}.png`),
  };
}));
```

Note that your build tools may not natively support this, so you might need to do some fiddling around there to get the settings/loaders right.